Is linear interpolation of a conservative map conservative in general?
Assume $x_0$ ~ P, $x_t = (1-t) x_0 + t \nabla \Phi(x_0)$ for some potential function $\Phi$? Is $E[ \nabla \Phi(x_0) - x_0 | x_t]$ curl-free?
Edit: What I know is that if $\Phi$ is convex, then the trajectory will have no intersections. In this case, $E[\nabla \Phi(x_0) - x_0 | x_t] = \nabla \Phi(x_0) - x_0$, which is curl-free. But I wonder if this is the case for more general $\Phi$.

What have you tried so far?

What I know is that if $\Phi$ is convex, then the trajectory will have no intersections. In this case, $E[\nabla \Phi(x_0) - x_0 | x_t] = \nabla \Phi(x_0) - x_0$, which is curl-free. But I wonder if this is the case for more general $\Phi$.

Please include those details in the question rather than the comments. It'll give people more context and improve your chances of getting an answer.
